# cant get the data I want from two different tables using Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have a table called **instructor_class**: *user_id, class_id* and I have another table **classes**: *id, time, active*.

I would like to show classes for a single user but only those classes that active is 0 or 1.

My current code looks like this:

```
return InstructorClass::with('classes.session')->where('user_id', '=', $userId)->get();
```

This code is displaying me everything, then I tried the following code:

```
$active = 1;
return InstructorClass::with(['classes' => function ($q) use ($active) {
            $q->where('active', '=', $active); // '=' is optional
        }])
            ->where('user_id', '=', $userId)
            ->get();
```

This again returns me same records, but of course the class property is null for each record, which at some point looks correct, but my point is if the 'active' field does not corresponds at the classes table do not show the record, seems like the where() stm within with() is optional..

I am kinda stuck here...
Would appreciate your help, opinions!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `::has('classes')` to only return the models that have related classes

```
return InstructorClass::has('classes')->with(['classes' => function ($q) use ($active) {
    $q->where('active', $active);
}])
->where('user_id', '=', $userId)
->get();
```

Comment: not working, getting same result which I dont want! I still get records even there is no class with active = 1

Answer (score 0):

Never thought it could be this simple:

```
return InstructorClass::with('classes.session')
            ->join('classes', 'classes.id', '=', 'instructor_class.class_id')
            ->where('classes.active', '=', 1)
            ->where('user_id', '=', $userId)
            ->get();
```